# How to give priority order for cucumber.io 5.6.0 after hooks and a specific tag

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

I trying to update my knowledge in Cucumber, but some features are very hard to find or change. Right know I'm trying and failing to find the way. I tried and can use in step definitions various hooks @After and define the order **or** conditional hooks like a featured tag but can't do both. Any idea if it's possible to do both in the newest version?! If yes, how to do it? Please!

https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?sbsearch=CucumberOptions#hooks

exemple (for the tag use):

```
@After("not @unit")
public void screenshot(Scenario scenario) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
    }
}
@After("not @unit")
    public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.quit();
}
```

exemple (for the order):

```
@After(order = 10)
public void screenshot(Scenario scenario) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
    }
}
@After(order = 0)
    public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.quit();
}
```

In old cukes version it was possible to use:

```
@After(order = 1, value={"~@unit"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks no longer take multiple tags. Instead you use a single [tag expression](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tag-expressions). So the correct way to use hooks would be:

```java
@After(order = 1, value="(@firefox or @chrome) and not @unit")
public void screenshot(Scenario scenario) {

}
```